# Why does "int(''.join(map(str,numset)))" result in a ValueError in Python?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, int, python-itertools

So basically, I am converting a tuple, "numset", into a string iterable so I can join all the integers. Then, I turn it into an integer again. However, it is resulting in a **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

```
    import itertools

    arr = [1, 2, 3]

    for l in range(0, len(arr)+1):
        for numset in itertools.combinations(arr, l):
            print(numset)
            print ("".join(map(str,numset)))
            print(int("".join(map(str,numset))))
```

results in
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

The top two print statements work. I tried first converting it into a float then into an integer, but it gave the error `could not convert string to float`

Here are the outputs for the top two print statements, respectively.

```
()
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
1
2
3
12
13
23
123
```

failing data:

```
File "", line 16, in <module>
print(int("".join(map(str,numset))))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: What happened to the error? The idea is to print the input to the failing line.

Comment: First empty set (than turned into empty string) can't be converted into `int`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) documentation, *Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.*. Since you started your enumeration at 0, you got a zero length combination. Tweaking the debug prints a bit

```
import itertools

arr = [1, 2, 3]

for l in range(0, len(arr)+1):
    for numset in itertools.combinations(arr, l):
        print('data', repr(numset), repr("".join(map(str,numset))))
        print(int("".join(map(str,numset))))
```

shows

```
data () ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(int("".join(map(str,numset))))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Start your enumeration at 1

```
import itertools

arr = [1, 2, 3]

for l in range(1, len(arr)+1):
    for numset in itertools.combinations(arr, l):
        print('data', repr(numset), repr("".join(map(str,numset))))
        print(int("".join(map(str,numset))))
```

and you get your data

```
data (1,) '1'
1
data (2,) '2'
2
data (3,) '3'
3
data (1, 2) '12'
12
data (1, 3) '13'
13
data (2, 3) '23'
23
data (1, 2, 3) '123'
123
```

Comment: If @Jude__Tomas wants to convert elements of array into a string just like your solution shows, cant he use this simple code : ```arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr_to_str = ""
for i in arr:
    arr_to_str+=str(i)
print(arr_to_str) ```  rather than going into such complexity

Comment: @JenilDave - It can be hard to guess the full intent with example programs but I assume OP really does want all combinations as integers, not just a single string `"123"`. That could also be written as `"".join(str(v) for v in arr)`